# StyleCop Suppressions not Working

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

I've been trying to suppress a few StyleCop warnings and I'm not having any luck. Here is some informationt that may be helpful.

- StyleCop Version: 4.4.0.9
- Warnings to Suppress: SA1600, SA1633, SA1634

### What I've Tried

- Local suppression
- GlobalSupressions.cs file
- Project level .StyleCop file suppression
- Solution level .StyleCop file suppression
- Both of the aforementioned at the same time
- Merging of solution level .StyleCop file with project level .StyleCop file
- Merging with parent files and removing the project level .StyleCop file
- Holding one leg up, one hand behind my head, one eye closed, and rebuilding the solution...

At any rate, I'm running out of options to suppress these messages, I hope that somebody can help!

#### Example of Local Suppression

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented", Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
```

#### Example of Global Suppression

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented", Justification = "Reviewed. Suppression is OK here.")]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your local suppression?  Is it possible you have a small typo causing local suppression not to work?

Comment: @JTorres I have done so for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I tracked down the problem.  On my development box I had two versions of ReSharper installed and one of them was not supported by StyleCop.  Every time I upgraded StyleCop it warned me about that but indicated I could continue anyway.  The interesting part is that the lack of support for one version botched the support for another that was fully supported.

So, what I did was this.

1. Uninstall the unsupported version of ReSharper.
2. Dig through the registry deleting every entry for that version of ReSharper I could find so that the installer saw that it was gone.  This was an interesting procedure because the uninstallation of the unsupported version really doesn't do a good job of cleaning itself up - though I guess that shouldn't be surprising.

The second option was really a lot of trial an error - I would delete some entries and run the installer agian to see if it threw up the warning - once the warning wasn't showing anymore I continued with the installation and I can now suppress the documentation rules at the class level!

Thanks a lot (NOT) StyleCop for allowing an unsupported version of ReSharper to botch up the supported version - that was helpful - though less than it sounds!